# Is there a compile-to-javascript lisp?

Tags: javascript, compilation, lisp, scheme

I have recently started picking up some scheme, and am really liking it. However, I mostly work with Javascript(and coffeescript), and thus scheme isn't particularly useful to me. I suppose I could use it as a scripting language, but I use ruby and python for that.

So is there a Lisp out there that:

- Compiles to JS
- Is compatible with Javascript code
- Has decent docs

I realize this may not exist, as lisp isn't really mainstream, but if it does could someone point me to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 16 Lisp/Scheme languages that compile to Javascript listed at

[List of languages that compile to JS](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS)

I found this page by googling "convert scheme to javascript"

Comment: Huh, thats odd, searching "compile scheme to javascript" yielded me nothing of worth.

Comment: I just tried that and this page was still at the top of the list. Maybe it's because our search histories are different, and Google knows what I'm interested in.

Comment: I suppose that must be it. Anyway, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I will mark this answer as right.